# Python: How to select and then compare and filter certain values in a dict?

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

I have a dict which looks like this:

```
{
    'Amathus': [datetime.date(2022, 8, 10), datetime.time(1, 30), 'Wroclaw', Decimal('3.75'), 33.91], 
    'Falesia': [datetime.date(2022, 8, 10), datetime.time(1, 30), 'Wroclaw', Decimal('4.00'), 21.46], 
    'Diamond': [datetime.date(2022, 8, 10), datetime.time(1, 30), 'Posznan', Decimal('4.50'), 40.24], 
    'Kid': [datetime.date(2022, 8, 10), datetime.time(1, 30), 'Posznan', Decimal('4.50'), 42.24]
}
```

and so on.

I now want to select every Key that has the value "Wroclaw", these keys for the last value (74,14 for example) and only return the highest 3 keys with all values attached.

My try so far:

I get all the keys with this:

```
getkeys = [k for k, v in mydict.items() if city in v] #city is a variable, containing "Wroclaw"
newdict = {}
for k in getkeys :
    aupdate = {k :finaldict2[k]}
    newdict.update(aupdate)
sorteddict = sorted(newdict, key=newdict.get, reverse=True)
```

So far, so good - I now have the keys in the sorted order in a *list*. Now I could use sth like this to print the 3 highest values:

```
    counting = 0
    while counting <= 2:
        testvalue = newdict[sorteddict[counting]]
        print(sorteddict[counting],testvalue)
        counting += 1
```

But this feels so clonky and just not like the best solution, but this is a far as I come right now.

So how to improve this approach further? Any advice is appreciated :D

Comment: That's not a dict. It's a bunch of lists. A dict looks like `{key: value, key: value, ...}` You have no keys.

Comment: Is there a reason you use `newdict.update(aupdate)` instead of just `newdict[k] = finaldict2[k]`?

Comment: Or the dictionary comprehension `newdict = {k, finaldict2[k] for k in getkeys}`

Comment: corrected the dict  - messed up the format. @Barmar - not really.  I used update in my trial and error because tries with "=" did not work - for another reason. Could switch that back, but the whole approach felt clonky. As I said - learning and trial and error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the sorted list of keys.

```
result = sorted(newdict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)[:3]
```

This returns a list of `(key, value)` tuples.